# How to fix"Index out of range" error inside a viewController that's embedded as a child inside a TabBarViewController?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a TabBarViewController that's set as the initial viewController. Inside this tab Bar, I have added a viewController named PlayerViewController, as a child.  As you can tell by the name, this PlayerViewController loads and handles music playback. It contains and an array which I use to play the song and increment the array of songs.  This works fine but I have been trying to sit up a miniplayer that sits inside a containerView, which will be placed just above the tabBar items. So I placed the PlayerViewController inside this the TabBarViewController as a child, then I placed it inside a container declared inside this TabBarViewController, but it seems since the TabBarViewController is the initial viewController that gets called first, I get an "index out of range" error in the playerViewController.  If I comment out all the code inside the TabBarViewController, the audio works fine as you'd expect.

Here's the playerVC

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    public var songArray: [Songs] = []
   public  var position: Int = 0
    
    @IBOutlet var holder: UIView!
    
    var playButton: UIButton!
    var backButton: UIButton!
    var forwardButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureAudio()
        print("our count inside the playervc is \(songArray.count)")
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemIndigo
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if view.subviews.count == 0 {
            configureAudio()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if let player = player {
            player.stop()
        }
    }


    func configureAudio(){

        let song = songArray[position]

        let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: song.songName, ofType: "mp3")

        do{
          try  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            guard let urlString = urlString
            else{return}

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
            guard let player = player else{return}
            player.play()

        }

        catch{
            print("error occured")
        }
        configureUI()
    }
    
    
    func configureUI(){
        playButton = UIButton()
        playButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        playButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.fill"), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(playButton)
        
        backButton = UIButton()
        backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "backward.fill"), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(backButton)
        
        
        forwardButton = UIButton()
        forwardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        forwardButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "forward.fill"), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(forwardButton)
        
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            playButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            playButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            
            
            backButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            
            forwardButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            forwardButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15)
        
        ])
    }

   
   

}
```

and here's the TabBarVC which is the initial VC.

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    var position: Int = 0
    var songArray: [Songs] = []
    lazy var PlayerVC: PlayerViewController = {
        let PlayerVC = PlayerViewController()
        PlayerVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return PlayerVC
    }()
    
    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let uiView = UIView()
        uiView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return uiView
    }()
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addchildViews()
        setConstraints()
       
    }

    
    func addchildViews()
    {
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        addChild(PlayerVC)
        containerView.addSubview(PlayerVC.view)
        PlayerVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        viewControllers?.remove(at: (viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: PlayerVC))!)
    }

    
    func setConstraints()
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75.0),
            
            
            
            PlayerVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            PlayerVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            PlayerVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            PlayerVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
        
        ])

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PlayerViewController` declares `var songArray: [Songs] = []` and `var position: Int = 0`. Then later you do `let song = songArray[position]`.

You can't access index 0 of an empty array, hence the crash and error message.

Nowhere in the code you posted do you ever set `songArray`. But even if you did, you need to guard against `position` being too large for the array.

```
func configureAudio(){
    guard position < songArray.count else { return } // Add this

    let song = songArray[position]
```

Comment: I set the array and position when I instantiate the playerviewcontroller from a tableView controller.  So it's correctly set and it works until I try to access the playerviewcontroller from tabBarViewController.  My conclusion after some digging is that the tab Bar is getting called before the array is field in the playerViewController.

Comment: The code you posted shows you creating `PlayerViewController` right in the tab bar controller. But you never set the `songArray` there. That's the problem. When you then attempt to add `PlayerVC` as a child controller, `viewDidLoad` is called which calls `configureAudio()`. And then you attempt to access index 0 of an empty array. That is the problem with the code you posted. My answer shows one solution. Another would be to set the `songArray` before trying to make it a child controller.